# Android bluetooth intent

Tags: java, android, user-interface, bluetooth, file-transfer

I want to send a file through my code. I know the file path, and that I want to do it through bluetooth. When I call this intent,  it displays a popup asking if I want to send the file through bluetooth, gmail, facebook, etc.

```
   Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); i.setType("text/plain");    
   i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(path)); 
   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send File"));
```

Is there a way to skip this popup step and specify that I want to do it through bluetooth all the time?

Also if I knew the address of the bluetooth device I want to send it to, is there a way to specify that as well through the code in the intent?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can have a try for this code, it works for me! it would only choose Bluetooth as you 
want

```
intent.setPackage("com.android.bluetooth");
```